# "File not found' when saving collections,forms, and singleton in Cockpit CMS

Tags: php, apache2, cockpit-cms

I've recently installed Cockpit CMS on Apache. Doing some customization on its UI. Everything was okay until I've changed its header icon then whenever I tried to save something on Collections, Forms, Singletons, or even adding entry, it says "File not found". I'm stuck in it.

I didn't touch any single code on its config and modules. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my cockpit.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cockpit
 ServerName  [My Server's IP]
 ServerAlias www.example.com

 <Directory /var/www/html/cockpit/>
      Options FollowSymlinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 <Directory /var/www/html/cockpit/>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [PT,L]
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try and save your collections or whatever and it gives an error that says "File not found" give permissions to the storage folder itself along with all of its subfolders. It helped me big time